# Pythonic way of printing tuple elements vertically and in alphabetical order

Tags: python

I have a list of namedtuples and want to be able to print the elements of a tuple in a way so that it would be easy to easy to read.  Each row of the list contains about 50+ namedtuple elements.

```
namedtuple = ('apple', 'box', 'cat', 'dog', 'phone', 'elephant', 'horse', 'goose', 'frog')
```

Desired Output:

```
apple   dog        goose 
box     elephant   horse
cat     frog
```

Comment: what does "namedtuple" refer to here? it's a specific term in Python which does not seem to be used in your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Printing Lists as Tabular Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: What you have is a tuple of strings - [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) are a very specific datatype in Python which is not used here.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: sort the tuple.

```
sortedtuple = sorted(namedtuple)
```

Step 2: divide the tuple into columns.

```
num_rows = (len(sortedtuple) + num_columns-1) // num_columns
columns = [sortedtuple[i*num_rows:(i+1)*num_rows] for i in range(num_columns)]
```

Step 3: extend the last column with blanks so it's the same size as the others.

```
columns[-1] = columns[-1] + ['']*(len(columns[0])-len(columns[-1]))
```

Step 4: iterate over a zipped list of columns and print them.

```
width = max(len(word) for word in sortedtuple)
for row in zip(*columns):
    print '  '.join(word + ' '*(width- len(word)) for word in row)
```

Comment: The number of rows you have here is incorrect - should be `len(...) + num_columns - 1` to round the division result up correctly. Otherwise with 3 values in 3 columns you get 2 rows.
Also, there is no need to allocate additional lists for the columns themselves.

Comment: @JakubWasilewski, thanks for the correction. It was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

For printing ASCII tables with Python, I used PrettyTable some time ago with success: https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/

As to the sorting, just use the built in `sorted()` function; then take equal sized slices from the tuple and add them to the PrettyTable object.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing it (Python 3 - you did not specify 2.x or 3.x), where `columns` is the desired number of columns:

```
def print_in_columns(values, columns):
  values = sorted(values) # for alphabetical order
  column_width = max(len(s) for s in values) + 2 # you could pick this explicitly
  rows = (len(values) + columns - 1) // columns # rounding up
  format = "{:" + str(column_width) + "}"
  for row in range(rows):
    for value in values[row::rows]:
      print(format.format(value), end="")
    print()
```

Each row you print is simply a slice of the original tuple, with the right step value.